# Problem displaying json file

Tags: jquery, json

I am trying to display these arrays using jquery/json but i keep getting undefined.

Also, how can i display is without the user clicking "A" ?

thanks in advance

```
== jSON file ==

// JSON
{
"items": [
{
"title": "welcoem home",
"author": "Charles Dickens"
},
{
"title": "Harry Potter",
"author": "J rowling"
}
]
}

==

<script language="javascript" >
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#letter-a a').click(function() {
    $.getJSON('q3.json', function(data) {
      $('#dictionary').empty();
      $.each(data, function(entryIndex, entry) {
        var html = '<div class="entry">';
        html += '<h3 class="term">' + entry['title'] + '</h3>';
        html += '<div class="part">' + entry['author'] + '</div>';
        html += '<div class="definition">';
        html += entry['definition'];
        if (entry['items']) {
          html += '<div class="quote">';
          $.each(entry['items'], function(lineIndex, line) {
            html += '<div class="quote-line">' + line + '</div>';
          });
          if (entry['author']) {
            html += '<div class="quote-author">' + entry['author'] + '</div>';
          }
          html += '</div>';
        }
        html += '</div>';
        html += '</div>';
        $('#dictionary').append(html);
      });
    });
    return false;
  });
});


</script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="json.css" type="text/css" />
</head>

<body>
<div id="container">
        <div id="header">
        <h2>json stuff</h2>
        </div>

        <div class="letters">
                <div class="letter" id="letter-a">
                <h3><a href="#">A</a></h3>
                </div>      

        </div>
        <div id="dictionary">

        </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason you were having problems here is because you were looping through the wrong level in the array when you called `$.each(data)`.

Your code inside that `$.each(data)` expects be looping through an array of items, but in fact, it is looping through the array keys of `data` itself, of which there is only one, that being `items`.

The fix is simple: change data`in your`each()`call to be`data.items`.

The line of code now looks like this:

```
$.each(data.items, function(entryIndex, entry) {
```

Hope that helps. (even if it is a bit late)